# Errors were encountered while processing: hspa-modem-dkms

Tags: dkms

I get this error whenever I try installing something

```
Errors were encountered while processing:

hspa-modem-dkms

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And the installation stops abnormally. Please someone help me . How to fix this error ? 
Thank you.

Comment: What is that something you are trying to install?

Comment: anything using apt-get , even update gets aborted

Comment: Can you add the output before the "errors were encountered.." line?  We need that to find out what the package broke.